# Find field by its angularjs model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Can I somehow find the field corresponding with a given angularjs model? I know, that there may be multiple fields corresponding with a single variable, or none, but this is not a problem.

For example, there's an `input ng-model=users[2].name`, I want a method taking the string `"users[2].name"` and returning the DOM element.

I needn't be fast, as I want it for a sort of demo of user input, e.g., if the user should fill the name field, I move an (mouse simulating) overlay to it and fill it programmatically. Si

I can do it via jquery, but this is rather cumbersome, as it's hardly ever as straightforward as the selector`input[ng-model="user[0].name"]`. It's typically buried in `ng-repeat="user in users"` and that several levels deep. Or worse, in a mixture of `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

A solution changing `users[2].name` and then finding the changed DOM elements would probably be alright, too.

I created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DiBDAUEfPVMEhDndZvh8?p=info) hopefully showing what I wanted.

Comment: No you can't, not based on what you've described.

What you can do though is create a new directive also on the element and then you can hook into that.

Comment: You may try to add a directive named `ng-model` and try to do some stuff with that... This (http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/tip-directives-with-the-same-name/) may be interesting.

Comment: can you provide a plunk?

Comment: @GilBirman Done (my very first plunk).

Comment: I think that it's possible if your `ng-model` expression has a dot, otherwise the binding doesn't exist to detect the temporary change. An alternative is to store XPath selectors to all possible matches before the temporary change, and then retest the new elements that are created after the digest cycle.

Comment: @GilBirman All my expression have a dot. Why have you deleted your answer? No matter if you think it's wrong or you have a better idea, leave it there. I hadn't the time to look at it thoroughly, but I will.

Comment: @maaartinus the expression in `<input ng-model="y" />` does not have a dot. I undeleted my answer for you, but it's wrong unfortunately...

Comment: @GilBirman You're right concerning `y`, but this is just an imperfect example (feel free to fix or ignore the problem). The original is more complicated and has dots everywhere... And even if it hadn't, I'm sure dots are *at least* nearly everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this answer because it actually works, unlike my original answer. Also this is a much different approach so I didn't want to just tack it on to that one.

> > Caveat: **this works if your ng-model expression has a dot, otherwise the prototypical inheritance chain doesn't exist to propagate the temporary change.**

### [>>The Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/L4DQo5GMUPWZbrzNiicd?p=preview)

### Overview

First, we decorate the `ng-model` directive in order to track all `ng-model`s in the app. These models are stored in the `myModels` array. Then we loop through `myModels` looking for all models that evaluate to the value we're looking for and push them into the `possibleMatches` array. Finally, we change the target value and loop through `possibleMatches` to determine which one actually changed.

#### The code:

```
angular.module('find_by_model', [])

.constant('myModels', [])

.config(function($provide, myModels) {
  window.myModels = myModels; // just for debugging

  $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', function($delegate) {

    var directive = $delegate[0];

    var compile = directive.compile;

    directive.compile = function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var link = compile.apply(this, arguments);
      tElement.append('<div>Added in the decorator</div>');
      return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        link.apply(this, arguments);
        v = scope.$eval(tAttrs.ngModel);
        myModels.push({scope: scope, elem:elem,
          val: function() {
            return scope.$eval(tAttrs.ngModel);
          },
        }); 
      }; 
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
})

.factory('finder', function (myModels) {
  function findElem($scope, path) {
    var originalVal = $scope.$eval(path),
        possibleMatches = [],
        result = null;

    angular.forEach(myModels, function (model) {
      if (angular.equals(model.val(), originalVal)) possibleMatches.push(model);
    });

    // temp change: the blah property is arbitrary
    try {
      var newVal = $scope.$eval(path + " = " + JSON.stringify({ val: path, blah: 'changed'}) );
    } catch(e) {
      return null;
    } 

    // find it: note: this could be made more efficient with a breaking loop
    angular.forEach(possibleMatches, function (model) {
      if (angular.equals(model.val(),newVal)) result = model;
    });

    // reset
    $scope.$eval(path + " = " + JSON.stringify(originalVal));

    return result && result.elem;
  }

  return {
    findElem: findElem
  }
})
```

#### And here is how you use it (assuming you've already injected `finder`):

```
  $scope.expressionToFind = "m.top[0].name";

  var el = finder.findElem($scope, $scope.expressionToFind);
  if (el) 
    angular.element(el).css('outline', '1px solid red');
  else
    alert('not found');
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: maaartinus asked me to **un**-deleted this answer, but **it is wrong**

---

Here's an answer written in a combination of psuedo-code and JavaScript...

```
function findElem() {
  var originalVal = users[2].name
  var possibleMatches = []

  for each elem in the page:
    ngElem = angular.element(elem);

    var id = 0
    for each watcher in ngElem.scope().$$watchers
      if (watcher.last === originalVal) {
        possibleMatches.push({ngElem: ngElem, watcherId: id})
      }
      id++

  var changedVal = users[2].name = users[2].name + 'changed'
  $scope.$apply()

  for each possibleMatch in possibleMatches
    var s = possibleMatch.ngElem.scope()
    var mid = possibleMatch.watcherId
    if (s.$$watchers[mid].last == changedVal)
      return ngElem; // found

  return null; // not found
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why this doesn't work? I haven't tried it at all, but it sounds simple and logical.

Comment: @maaartinus I think that the main reason it doesn't work is because the `ngElem` stored in `possibleMatches` is useless when an `ngModel` value changes. That's because `ng-repeat` doesn't re-use old dom elements, rather it replaces them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of accessing the element within a directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2gU3d7UMYG1D7nWMjbvo?p=preview

If for some reason you cannot modify the html here is a way outside of angular:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var ele=getElementsByModel(document,'name');
  for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
    ele[i].style.border='solid 1px green';
  }
}
function getElementsByModel(baseElement,modelName){
  var nodes = baseElement.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var targetNodes=[];
  for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    var ngModel=nodes[i].getAttribute('ng-model');
    if(ngModel&&ngModel===modelName){ 
      targetNodes.push(nodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return targetNodes;
}
```

Comment: this technique will not work inside a repeater, and your plunker requires modification to the html, thus defeating the purpose